# How to better organize iOS and Android apps project management for the same project in JIRA

Tags: android, ios, project, project-management, jira

I have a project.
This project includes 2 apps: iOS and Android.
Apps are similar (doing the same but for different OSes).
The project is considered as completed when and only when both apps are delivered.

Apps then could evolve independently (in versions sense, for ex. there could be 1.3 iOS version versus  1.1 Android one).

I use JIRA for project management.

I wonder how better to organize this project with JIRA.

**Option #1:**
Create one project and one confluence space for it.
Create one user story per feature and then create sub-tasks inside for both iOS and Android (duplicate subtasks).
Looks messy. And it looks it is hard to recognize which app is in trouble as the whole project is in the same pot.

**Option #2:**
Create two projects (for iOS and for Android) and one confluence space. Then create stories per project (duplicate stories).
Looks more manageable, but stories duplication looks awful.

Please, help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Minimize the number of projects, so choose option 1. Use components to differentiate between each kind of subtask. Use another JIRA Agile board (or dashboard) to select just one set of subtasks or the other.

Comment: Thanks I will try option one and see how it'll work. I will report soon.

Comment: @DaddyM Sorry for calling you back but I'd love to hear your report as I'm sure many others would also. I have a similar problem and am not sure which course to take.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using 2 projects, only because the iOS & Android applications may diverge at some point. JIRA allows you to combine all of your projects into a single view with JIRA Agile and JQL.

You can even view them natively on your iOS device using the JIRA Board app: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/jira-board-kanban-scrum-agile/id934196108?mt=8

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this question belongs here but anyway, it's better to have one application and after you add a task for the iOS team with component iOS e.g., clone that task for Android, and add it under another component, because these tasks might differ in the delivery time, assignees, etc...

Comment: Thanks. You've meant "project" not "application" haven't you?

Comment: I am sorry yes, I mean project :) we usually work with mobile apps so it was an honest mistake :)

Answer (score 1):

I have had this problem for months now, but today I finally found a solution that works us.

When creating a task you can tag it using a label (name it either iOS or Android). I then use the label in quick filters, which allows me to filter on either iOS or Android tasks. Showing only the tasks for one of them.

Board - confirgure - quick filter ENTER labels=iOS

You keep the tasks in one board, and its less messy.

Comment: I think you're misusing the labels. You could do the same with components. Components in comparison to tags provide special support for charts etc.

Answer (score 0):

Use the components feature under project.
Project "FACETIND"
Component "IOS"
Component "DROID"